# Use Link tag and pass data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an if-else situation, in the else situation I am trying to load data from a Component as well as pass data into it.
The code for that is something like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom' ;
//import data from '../data.json';
import { withRouter, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import {FullBlog} from './FullBlog.js'


class Author extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      data:this.props.data,
      load:false,
      content:'',
    }
    this.loadBlog=this.loadBlog.bind(this);
  }

  loadBlog(i){
    that.setState({
     load:true,
    })
//  this.props.router.history.push('/fullblog');

  //window.location='/fullblog'+this.state.data;

  browserHistory.push('/fullblog')

  }
  render(){

   if(this.state.load===false){    
      return(

      <div onClick={this.loadBlog.bind(this,this.props.i)} className="box">
       <div>{this.props.i}</div>
          <div>{this.props.data.Author}</div>
          <div>{this.props.data.Book}</div>
        </div>

        )
       }//else{
       //   //return(<div><FullBlog data={this.state.data}/></div>)
       // }
  }
}

The function is loadBlog in which I tried to use browserHistory.push() but I don't know how can I pass data into the same and also I get error `'Cannot read property push of undefined.'`
```

Then, I tried using the Link tag like this

```
  if(this.state.load===false){    
      return(

      <Link to={'/fullblog'+this.props.data}><div onClick={this.loadBlog.bind(this,this.props.i)} className="box">
       <div>{this.props.i}</div>
          <div>{this.props.data.Author}</div>
          <div>{this.props.data.Book}</div>
        </div>
       </Link>
        )
       }//else{
       //   //return(<div><FullBlog data={this.state.data}/></div>)
       // }
  }
}
```

For the above, I get error as `invalid react element`.
What is the correct way of implementing the same.I am using react-router v4.

Edit:

Updated the code to

```
<div>
      <Link to={'/fullblog/${this.props.data}'}/><div onClick={this.loadBlog.bind(this,this.props.i)} className="box">
       <div>{this.props.i}</div>
          <div>{this.props.data.Author}</div>
          <div>{this.props.data.Book}</div>
        </div>

       </div>
```

I get Invariant violation error and React element error for the above.

Comment: check to make sure the you are importing `react-router` correctly

Comment: how can I check that? @JosanIracheta

Comment: check that the path is correct

Comment: okay, yes that is correct @JosanIracheta

Comment: I think your problem might be in the syntax. `<Link />` is a component but you're writing it like an `HTML Element`. Get rid of the `</Link>` at the bottom and wrap everything in a `<div></div>`

Comment: I am getting syntax error in <Link +this.props.data> @JosanIracheta

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149833/discussion-between-josan-iracheta-and-user7816606).

Comment: You can actually use [Link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md) to wrap a children element (thus, close it with </Link>)

Answer (score 1):

You should be returning something in the else part as well. Uncomment, the code from else block.

Comment: I would go for a pattern where you always return a variable (like in my code example)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning undefined. You always need to return a React component in the `render` method. What you can do is the following, as it's a common pattern:

```
render(){
  let content = (
    <p>I'm returning this by default</p>
  );

 if (this.state.load===false) {    
    content = (
      <div onClick={this.loadBlog.bind(this,this.props.i)} className="box">
        <div>{this.props.i}</div>
        <div>{this.props.data.Author}</div>
        <div>{this.props.data.Book}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return content;
}
```

I would recommend you to use [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) plus the [Airbnb](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb) specific configuration. This will help you avoid this kind of errors and use good patterns.